# HTTP Referrer from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

My web site has a dropdown control that allows the user to navigate to sub sections of my site.  On the root page I want to retrieve the HTTP_REFERER variable to determine if the user arrived from a sub site or from somewhere externally from my site.

The dropdown us using the this javascript to direct the user to the selected site:

```
window.location.href(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)
```

This appears to work but is proving to be unreliable in some browsers for whatever reason. In some cases the user selects a sub site from the dropdown and subsequently uses it again to return to the root site where I surprisingly find the HTTP_REFERER empty.  On other browsers it works fine.

So I am looking for a fool-proof, cross-browser script that I can use in my dropdown which will insure the HTTP_REFERER value is present.

Thanks

Comment: You should know that while most browsers do supply the referrer, it isn't required.  Furthermore, it is never "fool proof".  Clients can always fake it, especially in JS.

Comment: `window.location.href` is **not** a function.

Comment: not a function? what do you call it?

Answer (score 2):

You should not depend on HTTP referer header. It is not reliable and someone can block it if they want. I do block my referer to prevent the website to get my visiting information.

Comment: While it is true that HTTP referer (sic) shouldn't be relied upon, this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ The point is that there is no "fool proof" if you want to use http referer.

Comment: I was afraid of that answer.  However, in my case when the user clicks an anchor tag <a> which directs the user to my root page the HTTP_Referrer *IS* present.  So I think the question is: is there a better using way to simulate a user clicking an <a> tag rather than:


select onchange="window.location.href(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">

Answer (score 0):

Browsers like Firefox have lots of options that user can customize, one of these option is to hide referer on websites, because as you can read on wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer

> Because referrer information can violate privacy, some web browsers allow the user to disable the sending of referrer information.

Browsers by default send referer, it needs to be disabled by user, and you can't stop user from doing it.